# SMTP c# MailKit smtp.Authenticate fails

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am trying to send an e-mail using c# MailKit SMTP (code below).
It connects successfully (with `Connect` method) and then it fails on `Authenticate` method call with an error " Username and Password not accepted.". I know the user name and password are correct. I also tried `"mail.optusnet.com.au"` server on port 25 - same story.
What is wrong with my call to `smtp.Connect` method. I have spent whole day experimenting and got nowhere. Can somebody help please.

```
// send email
using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

smtp.Authenticate("rejkid@gmail.com", "Password1");

smtp.Send(email);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

Comment: My password is actually Password@1 - I don't know if it the @ character changes anything

Answer (score 0):

Google no longer allows your password to be used when authenticating via SMTP, POP3 or IMAP.

You either need to use OAuth2 or you need to enable 2FA on your Google account and then generate an app-specific password and use that.